# Cached data structure design

Tags: c++, data-structures

I've got a C++ program that needs to access this wind data, refreshed every 6 hours.  As clients of the server need the data, the server queries the database and provides the data to the client.  The client will use lat, lon, and mb as keys to find the the 5 values.

```
+------------+-------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-------+------+------+
| id         | lat   | lon | mb  | wind_dir | wind_spd | uv    | vv   | ts   |
+------------+-------+-----+-----+----------+----------+-------+------+------+
| 1769584117 | -90.0 | 0.0 | 100 |      125 |        9 | -3.74 | 2.62 | 2112 |
| 1769584118 | -90.0 | 0.5 | 100 |      125 |        9 | -3.76 | 2.59 | 2112 |
| 1769584119 | -90.0 | 1.0 | 100 |      124 |        9 | -3.78 | 2.56 | 2112 |
```

Because the data changes so infrequently, I'd like the data to be cached by the server so if a client needs data previously queried, a second SQL query is not necessary.

I'm trying to determine the most efficient in-memory data structure, in terms of storage/speed, but more importantly, ease of access.

My initial thought was a map keyed by lat, containing a map keyed by lon, containing a map keyed by mb for which the value is a map containing the wind_dir, wind_speed, uv, vv and ts fields.

However, that gets complicated fast.  Another thought of course is a 3-dimensional array (lat, lon, mb indices) containing a struct of the last 5 fields.

As I'm sitting here, I came up with the thought of combining lat, lon and mb into a string, which could be used as an index into a map, given that I'm 99% sure the combination of lat, lon and mb would always be unique.

What other ideas make sense?

Edit:  More detail from comment below

In terms of data, there are 3,119,040 rows in the data set. That will be fairly constant, though it may slowly grow over the years as new reporting stations are added. There are generally between 700 and 1500 clients requesting the data. The clients are flight simulators. They'll be requesting the data every 5 minutes by default, though the maximum possible frequency would be every 30 seconds. There is not additional information - what you see above is the data desired to return.

One final note I forgot to mention: I'm quite rusty in my C++ and especially STL stuff, so the simpler, the better.

Comment: map of map of map is not so complicated. Once you define it, you have `cache[lat][lon][mb]` and you get your data right there! It's also quite fast. Not as fast as a hash map, but acceptable

Comment: I personally would use the string combination as the hash key; but I would cache at the client rather then the server.

Comment: How about retaining the same table structure in a memory mapped [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) file?

Comment: @jake, in case of combination, a struct of the three values makes more sense than a string!

Comment: @Shahbaz I think it really depends on what else the cache does. Vikas' suggestion is plausible too.

Comment: @wadesworld, try giving us more information. For example, how many users do you have? How much data will be there in the database? How frequent do users want to access these data? Are there any other information linked to these data?

Comment: How is the data passed back to the requester?  If it's just one big string, store it as one big string.  If it's individual values, create a new type to store each of the values independently in whatever type the requester needs.  i.e. do what ever is easiest to set data back to the requester without converting it.

Comment: Are you over-engineering this?   How much data are we talking about, in total?

Comment: In terms of data, there are 3,119,040 rows in the data set.  That will be fairly constant, though it may slowly grow over the years as new reporting stations are added.  There are generally between 700 and 1500 clients requesting the data.  The clients are flight simulators.  They'll be requesting the data every 5 minutes by default, though the maximum possible frequency would be every 30 seconds.  There is not additional information - what you see above is the data desired to return.

Comment: One final note I forgot to mention:  I'm quite rusty in my C++ and especially STL stuff, so the simpler, the better.

Comment: With that few requests, I'd say any of the solutions works fine! Just go with `map`, you'd learn something in the process too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::map` with a three part key and a suitable less than operator (this is what Crazy Eddie proposed, extended with some lines of code)

```
struct key
{
    double mLat;
    double mLon;
    double mMb;
    key(double lat, double lon, double mb) :
        mLat(lat), mLon(lon), mMb(mb) {}
};

bool operator<(const key& a, const key& b)
{
    return (a.lat <  b.lat ||
            a.lat == b.lat && a.lon <  b.lon ||
            a.lat == b.lat && a.lon == b.lon && a.mb < b.mb);
}
```

Defining and inserting into the map would look like:

```
std::map<key, your_wind_struct> values;
values[key(-90.0, 0.0, 100)] = your_wind_struct(1769584117, 125, ...);
```

Comment: Although a map of map of map probably has faster look up

Comment: @Shahbaz: Thanks for fixing the code. I don't know which version would be faster. [A comparison shows that both (multipart key vs. nested map) are nearly equal in performance](http://ideone.com/BA9OB).

Comment: Going to accept this one since it's the closest to @Shahbaz's suggestions and extra credit for providing example code.

Answer (score 0):

A sorted vector also makes sense.  You can feed it a less predicate that compares your three part key.  You could do the same with a map or set.  A hash...  Depends on a lot of factors which container you chose.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the c++11 unordered_set, which uses a hash table instead of red black tree as the internal data structure, and gives (I believe) an amortized lookup time of O(1) vs O(logn) for red-black. Which data structure you use depends on the characteristics of the data in question - how many pieces of data, how often will a particular record likely be accessed, etc. I'm in agreement with several commentors, that using a structure as a key is the cleanest way to go.  It also allows you to more simply alter what the unique key is, should that change in the future; you would just need to add a member to your key structure, and not create a whole new level of maps.